# Experiencing error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate')

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

The other routes are working but this one is giving me `'undefined is not an object ('evaluating 'navigation.navigate)`. I've used `this.props.navigation.navigate('review')` but same issue.

The other routes are working but this one is giving me `'undefined is not an object ('evaluating 'navigation.navigate)`. I've used `this.props.navigation.navigate('review')` but same issue.

First file: Want to navigate to review screen.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { TouchableWithoutFeedback, View } from 'react-native';
import { List, ListItem, Button } from 'react-native-elements';

class Items extends Component {

    onRowPress = ({ navigation }) => {

        navigation.navigate('review');
    }


    render() {
        const { name } = this.props.employee;
        return (
            <View>
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.onRowPress}>
                <List>
                    <ListItem
                        roundAvatar
                        title={name}
                        chevronColor='purple'
                    />
                </List>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
            </View>
        );
    }
}


export default Items;
```

Second file: Items is imported here.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, ActivityIndicator, ListView } from 'react-native';
import { Button, Icon } from 'react-native-elements';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Items from '../components/ListItem';



import { employeesFetch } from '../actions';

class MapScreen extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'Map',
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => {
            return <Icon name='my-location' size={30} color={tintColor} />;
        }

    }

    state = {
        dataLoaded: false
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.employeesFetch();

        this.createDataSource(this.props);
    }
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.createDataSource(nextProps);
    }
    createDataSource({ employees }) {
        const ds = new ListView.DataSource({
            rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
        });
        this.dataSource = ds.cloneWithRows(employees);
    }
    renderRow(employee) {
        return <Items employee={employee} />;
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({ dataLoaded: true })
    }

    render () {
        if (!this.state.dataLoaded) {
            return (
                <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                    <ActivityIndicator size='large' />
                </View>
            );
        }
        return (
            <ListView
                enableEmptySections
                dataSource={this.dataSource}
                renderRow={this.renderRow} 
            />
        );
    }
}
```

Is there a way around this? I've been debugging this forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your **MapScreen** is registered in the `navigator`,

you need to pass the `navigation prop` to your **Items Component**

```
renderRow = (employee) =>  { // For binding with this
        return <Items employee={employee} navigation={this.props.navigation} />;
    }
```

and in your **Items.js**

```
onRowPress = () => {
        const {navigation} = this.props
        navigation.navigate('review');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are actually many similar duplicates to this question already, but it'll be faster to just answer than dig up one that has the exact same error.

1. Your `MapScreen` component presumably has access to the `navigation` prop given that you setup your root navigator correctly and use it as a screen. **However**, your `Items` component does not have access to the `navigation` prop as it's not being passed into it either as a HOC or a prop. This is one reason why `onRowPress` is not working.

   - To fix this, either:

     1. pass `navigation` (or `navigate`) down as a prop so `Items` has access to it. Then access it with `this.props.navigation` in `onRowPress`, or
     2. bubble up `onRowPress` such that it becomes a prop that you pass down into `Items`. That way, you can define it in `MapScreen` instead where you have access to the `navigation` prop.
2. Your `onRowPress` needs to be fixed as well. You are attempting to destructure `navigation` out of thin air. You need to pass something in to be destructured or do the destructuring of props within the function.

Also, `ListView` has been deprecated so unless you are on an old version of React Native, you shouldn't be using it. Use `FlatList` or `SectionList` instead depending on your needs.